# Using with method on Builder class

Tags: php, laravel

The code below works fine if we remove the `with()` method. But if we use `with()`, I get the following error. Why can't I use `with()` on the Builder class (`::query`)? Are there other alternatives? I have tried different solutions but couldn't seem to work.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not
> exist.

```
public function getTaskDetails()
{
    return ProductionTask::query()
        ->latest()
        ->whereUserCanSee()
        ->paginate()
        ->when($this->renderByDate, function ($query) {
            return $query->sortBy('created_at');
        })
        ->with([
            'assignmentTests' => function ($q) {
                if ($this->renderByRating) {
                    return $q->orderBy('rating', 'desc');
                }
            }
        ])->get();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ...  you would need to use `load` instead of `with` since you have already executed the query and now have a Collection of Models (results ... not a Builder) or you would have to do the `with` call before the `paginate` call (which executes the query)

Comment: put pagination at the end. It terminates and executes the query the same as first, find and get.  When you post code here use three backticks ``` around your code blocks

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling the pagination, it terminates the query. You can try the following code. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
    public function getTaskDetails()
{
    ProductionTask::whereUserCanSee()->latest()->when($this->renderByDate, function ($query) {
        return $query->sortBy('created_at');
    })->with(['assignmentTests' => function ($q) {
        if ($this->renderByRating) {
            return $q->orderBy('rating', 'desc');
        }
    }])->paginate(15);

}
```